# JavaScript failing parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I need to filter some information. The information is coming from a JSON parse. I can't make it work. What I want is that the JSON is filtered into the HTML classes. I think I'm stupid

```
$.ajax({
    // Agenda
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'agendas',
    data: {results: 'events'},
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        $('.date, .country, .events').html('');
        $.each(response.results, function (index, result) {
            if (result.status)
                $('.date').append(result.server);
                $('.country').append(result.server);
                $('.events').append(result.server);
        });
    }
});
```

It would be lovely if someone could help me

JSON:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "events": {
            "id": 1,
            "date": "2022-05-06T00:00:00+00:00",
            "description": "test",
            "time": "2017-02-03T06:40:00+00:00",
            "location": "NL",
            "year": "2008",
            "event": "Idk"
        }
    },
    {
        "events": {
            "id": 2,
            "date": "2019-04-05T00:00:00+00:00",
            "description": "aasdasdasda",
            "time": "2017-02-03T15:04:00+00:00",
            "location": "asdasdasd",
            "year": "0000",
            "event": "asdasd"
        }
    }
]
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="day">
    <h2 class="date">Januari 23</h2>
    <div class="country-events">
        <span class="country">UK</span>
        <div class="events">
            <span class="event">Conference Amsterdam<br />11:00 CET</span>
            <span class="event">Webinar Copenhagen<br />15:00 CET</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I really can't get my head around this. I know it is not the correct code, I am new to JSON and JavaScript. 4th day currently so please forgive me.

Thank you in advance

UPDATE

[This is what it shows currently, the data from the json file needs to go in the specific elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm89t.png)

Comment: Rather than saying "*I can't make it work*", try to explain exactly *what* is going wrong with the code you've posted. Does it error? Does it produce unexpected output? People will be more able to help if they know what your issue is.

Comment: Your `result` object does not have a `status` property.

Comment: @evolutionxbox nor `server`.

Comment: Thats the problem, it does not error and it doesnt have an unexpected output. I am trying to find a solution for my problem but alas it hasn't been a cheerful day for me.

Comment: @DamianAshworth what is the solution you are looking for ?

Comment: @DamianAshworth from that JSON file you provided, what properties are trying to access? Post a desired output!

Comment: I just did didn't I? I desire to have the EVENT DATA in the html elements I suggested.

Comment: @DamianAshworth The disered output is the html code you expect to show up on the screen not a picture showing the error. Giving that JSON file you provided, what should the result be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(response.results, function(index, result) {
  console.log(result)
  $('.date').append(result.events.date);
  $('.date').append('</br>');
  $('.country').append(result.events.location);
  $('.country').append('</br>');
  $('.events').append(result.events.event);
  $('.events').append('</br>');

});
```

is this what you want?

https://plnkr.co/edit/wCYJPXgAPII1mcW4cKw7?p=preview

check this fiddle

Comment: I tried that, it still doesn't show anything on my dashboard

Comment: `response.results.date` is undefined see the JSON file he provided!

Comment: try the fiddle, it's basically what should be in your success method

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry, but can you be explicit about what doesn't work?

Comment: `response.results.date` will be `undefined` according to the JSON which the OP posted.

Comment: @evolutionxbox i guess you did not notice that my answer was edited and corrected, initially i was just trying to give out a logic but then made a fiddle with accurate scenario.

Comment: @AnkitKumarOjha - ah apologies. I did not notice. I should be more careful.